Reeh-Schlieder theorem: what's the matter with the Taj Mahal?
I'm currently struggling to understand the implications of the Reeh-Schlieder theorem - having little mastery of QFT formlism, let alone AQFT.
Its connection with vacuum state entanglement, although I have an intuitive idea of it, is far from perfectly clear to me, at the moment.
And then there's Reinhard Werner's statement that “By acting on the vacuum with suitable operations in a terrestrial laboratory, an experimenter can create the Taj Mahal on (or even behind) the Moon!” (quoted by Rainer Verch in this arXiv article).
https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0512053
My question is twofold. Could you make this connection intelligible to me; how, in short, the theorem presupposes the entanglement of the vacuum state of a field? And explain it to me in a not too formal way.
And secondly: how can we draw this implication that Werner seems to draw quite naturally? Do you have to be a supporter of Everett's theory to argue such as thing?

Do you understand (and agree with) Werner's statement in classical mechanics? It is clearly true, and we have already performed similar experiments. Indeed, by performing suitable operations in a lab on Earth, we were able to create a space probe close to Saturn. Well, it took some time for it to travel there, but it certainly showed up, eventually...

$\natural$

You know that those operators are not unitary right?

@AccidentalFourierTransform, so what you are saying is that when those operators are considered for all spacetime they are not local. That makes sense.

The Reeh-Schlieder theorem states that the action of local operators in a region $R$ on the vacuum state can produce operators spanning the Hilbert space of the QFT. If the vacuum state was not entangled then such operators couldn't span the entire Hilbert space of the QFT because that Hilbert space includes entangled states. For more explanation see Section 5 of this paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0112148
Since the set of all states includes one in which there is a Taj Mahal on the moon one could in principle produce a Taj Mahal on the moon by some local operation in the room in which I'm typing this answer. There are obviously operations by which I could do this, which involve things like making enough money to buy the materials to make a duplicate of the Taj Mahal, pay people to assemble the Taj Mahal and put it on a rocket going to the moon, not necessarily in that order.
What about interpretations? The Copenhagen and statistical interpretations say you can't give an account of what's happening in reality in quantum experiments so they can't really exclude anything including making a Taj Mahal on the moon. Nor can they help you understand it since they say explicitly that you're not supposed to understand anything about quantum theory. Other theories such as the pilot wave or spontaneous collapse theories can't currently reproduce the results of relativistic quantum theories:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
So those theories are irrelevant for understanding this issue. As for superdeterminism, it's difficult to find a more damning description of it then one given by one of its advocates:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.01324

The two biggest problem with superdeterminism at the moment are (a) the lack of a generally applicable fundamental theory and (b) the lack of experiment.

That leaves Everett as the only approach for understanding QFT.

Reeh-Schlieder theorem ensures that you can act with local opeators in your room and create a state in which there is Taj Mahal on the moon with probability one, not negligible. The issue is more that the combination of operators you act with would have to be very fine-tuned. Furthermore, "you can act" is an oversimplification as the theorem requires acting with non-unitary operators, which is not something an experimentalist could do.

alanf Thanks for the explanation (and the references!). The argument based on the entanglement of Hilbert space is particularly convincing !
And daring, this thesis concerning the Everett interpretation -- although I'm not unhappy, as it goes in the direction of my intuition. But does this mean that the “state in which the Taj Mahal is on the moon” “already” exists in one sense, superimposed and entangled with all the others, before measurement, and whatever our operations?

Peter Kravchukv I don't know Werner's exact statement, but in the Verch text quoted, it doesn't seem to me that the probability is one.
Furthermore, and at the risk of saying something stupid: aren't all operators of creation/annihilation, projection or measurement non-unitary (=not preserving the norm of the state vectors on which it acts)? And doesn't the experimentalist use them?

@PeterKravchuk You're correct. I modified the answer.

@alanf but the probability of all these operations following one another (in one order or another) is still negligible, isn't it? Why did you remove this element (I understand about the rest)?

@Husserliana The probability of those operations depends on whether I have the knowledge required to do the steps and on whether I want to do them. Since I lack both the knowledge and the motivation the probability happens to be negligible but not because of the the laws of physics per se. The argument given in the paper doesn't take into account the possibility of knowledge being used to arrange a non-negligible probability.

@alanf Is it then comparable to the dilution of superposition via decoherence? Superposition remains accessible in principle (it has not been reduced), but inaccessible FAPP (here too, due to lack of knowledge, experimental inability, etc.)... So a possibility in principle, but a practical impossibility?

@Husserliana The Taj Mahal won't appear on the moon as a result of the physical events in the absence of people creating knowledge. But nothing in the laws of physics precludes a person from making a Taj Mahal on the moon or shipping one there.

@alanf It makes sens. But then (and it will be my last intervention here, I promise), I find hard to understand Werner's statement. Bying materials, building the Taj Mahal
etc...  are certainly not "suitable operations in a terrestrial laboratory", nor the "local operation in the room" you were talking about in your answer. Do they even involve entanglement ?

Every action you take is constrained by the laws of physics. So the operations could consist of ones designed to make the lab into a place where you could make money to buy materials to make the Taj Mahal, send out instructions to make it and so on. All this would involve entanglement because entanglement explains basically all correlations between physical systems, it's just that in everyday life it's not well controlled so you can'tdo cryptography or teleportation of whatever with it.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
